# buildroot/busybox: launch bootchartd on startup

Tags: kernel, busybox, init, profiling

I built a custom linux image using [buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/) and [busybox](http://www.busybox.net/). To speed up the boot process I'd like to use [bootchartd](http://www.bootchart.org/) (built-in version of busybox) to profile the process. However bootchartd is not running, therefore no output file (*/var/log/bootchart.tgz*) is generated.

I appended each of these two lines to the kernel command line. Unfortunately, neither of them is working:

```
init=/sbin/bootchartd
```

Second version:

```
real_init=/sbin/bootchartd
```

Does anybody know why bootchartd isn't launched?

<sup>Note: initramfs as a root filesystem</sup>

Comment: But it is there, right? I.e. `bootchartd` in a console returns something?

Comment: Yes, it does what it is supposed to do (showing the usage). As soon as it's started with PID=1, it should start logging.

Comment: Can you verify that the initramfs stuff gets passed the parameter properly? ([cmp. this](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Bootchart#Initrd.2Finitramfs))

Comment: The first line of `dmesg` shows the passed arguments. However, I'm not quite sure if that is enough to proof that the parameters are passed properly. Do you know whether that suffices?

Comment: Probably not as it would work otherwise, wouldn't it?  Can you include more information, e.g. what distribution you use (if any, otherwise describing your setup, how you create your initramfs...)

Answer (score 1):

According to the Linux kernel source (namely, the file `init/main.c`), the ramdisk execute command is executed before `init=` and `real_init=`. This command is default to `/init` and can be configured via the `rdinit=` kernel command line parameter

But to collect logs properly bootchartd need to be started without any parameters, so it looks like patching of `init/main.c` is needed anyway, as its default parameter is `start`.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar problem to yours and came across your question during my research process. Though we do not have the same problem, I believe I found the answer to yours. So, according to [busybox's documentation](http://elinux.org/Bootchart):
- Note that if you're using an initramfs, you'll need

```
rdinit=/sbin/bootchartd
```